Terraform Error: Object Required, I can't find the error in the variable spec
I have the following variable declaration:
variable "environment" {
  type = object({
    SFTP = map(object({
      containers = list(object({
        name                  = string
        container_access_type = optional(string)
        metadata              = optional(map(string))
      }))
      users = list(object({
        name            = string
        home_directory  = optional(string)
        ssh_key_enabled = optional(bool, true)
        permissions_scopes = list(object({
          target_container = string
          permissions      = optional(list(string), ["All"])
        }))
        ssh_authorized_keys = optional(list(object({
          key         = string
          description = optional(string)
        })), [])
      }))
    }))
  })
}

and for it the base.auto.tfvars file:
environment = {
  SFTP = {
    containers = [
      {
        name                  = "sftp-container-1"
        container_access_type = "public"
        metadata              = {
          environment = "production"
        }
      }
    ]
    users = [
      {
        name            = "user1"
        home_directory  = "/home/user1"
        ssh_key_enabled = true
        permissions_scopes = [
          {
            target_container = "sftp-container-1"
            permissions      = ["Read", "Write"]
          },
          {
            target_container = "sftp-container-2"
            permissions      = ["All"]
          }
        ]
        ssh_authorized_keys = [
          {
            key         = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza user1@example.com"
            description = "User 1's SSH key"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

and running this, Terraform says:
The given value is not suitable for var.environment declared at infra-variables.tf:1,1-23: attribute "SFTP": element "containers": object required.
I'm sorry for this silly post, but I can't find it.
Thanks
Wolfgang

The type definition clashes with the value because SFTP's value should be a map(object), but instead an object is provided as the value. It is unclear which you intended, and so if you intended object you update the definition like:
type = object({
  SFTP = object({
    containers = list(object({
      name                  = string
      container_access_type = optional(string)
      metadata              = optional(map(string))
    }))
    users = list(object({
      name            = string
      home_directory  = optional(string)
      ssh_key_enabled = optional(bool, true)
      permissions_scopes = list(object({
        target_container = string
        permissions      = optional(list(string), ["All"])
      }))
      ssh_authorized_keys = optional(list(object({
        key         = string
        description = optional(string)
      })), [])
    }))
  })
})

but if you intended map(object) then you update the value like:
environment = {
  SFTP = {
    "some_descriptive_key" = {
      ...
    }
  }
}


Thank you very much! Now it dawns on me where I was going wrong.

@Wolfgang Please accept and upvote if it answered your question, or otherwise explain how it did not.

Sorry, too much a beginner in this, Done!
